# how to use a sql function as a query with where condition in java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I have a sql function with two inputs(id, date) via java code which I am using in my query in java. Query I am using is this:

```
select * from [dbo].[my_function](?,?) where LEAF='TRUE'
```

However it gives error as below:

```java
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select * from [dbo].[my_function] (?,?) where  leaf_node='TRUE']; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'dbo.my_function'.
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:645)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:680)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:712)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:722)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:772)
```

Could someone help me with this error?

Comment: Since you have `?` you need to provide `id` and  `date` values.
And also what data type is LEAF? If it is BIT, it should fail for sure.

Comment: Provide your prepared statement,, connection (no need of user credentials) and other related details as well